# Targeting all pages except top level pages

Tags: conditional-tags, template-tags

I have used `'0' == $post->post_parent` successfully in my templates to target top level pages.

However, I cannot seem to target all pages EXCEPT top level pages:

```
    <?php 
    if ( '0' !== $post->post_parent ) { 
        include 'siblings.php'; 
    } 
    ?>
```

Using the code above, the file is still included in top level pages.

Note, I can get it working using the code below, but I want to keep it flexible and not have to specify IDs:

```
    <?php 
    if ( !is_page( array( 8, 10, 12 )) && (is_tree(8) || is_tree(10) || is_tree(12)) ) { 
        include 'siblings.php'; 
    } 
    ?>
```

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <?php 
    if ( '0' != $post->post_parent) { 
        include 'siblings.php'; 
    } 
    ?>
```

`!==` refers to an exact type match too.
So your code doesn't work because the post id is stored as an integer.
`!=` will disregard the fact that you are comparing a string to a number.

Hope this helps.

You could also simply use the integer `0` in place of `'0'` in the first place...

Comment: Thanks Douglas, but that made no difference. However, I think this problem is more complex than originally thought! You see, I can use `if ( '0' != $post->post_parent)` to include other files no problem. Could be something dodgy in the included file? Oh dear!